# Cordova iOS App Getting White Flash between Launch Storyboard and First Screen

Tags: ios, cordova

I just converted an iOS Cordova app which used the SplashScreen plugin to use a Launch Storyboard so it would support iOS 9 multitasking on iPad. This works, but now I have a white flash between the launch storyboard and the first screen of the app. Before, when I was using the splashscreen plugin, I turned off AutomaticHideSplashScreen and used the splashscreen plugin API to hide it when I would be sure the rendering of the first screen would be finished.

Is there any way to do something similar, or at least delay the disappearance of the launch screen to give the webview time to render?

Comment: Same issue here. How did you fix this?

Comment: I have not fixed this yet.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the launch screen xib view as subview of the rootViewController view should fix this. Just add the following code in *application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method in the *AppDelegate.m* just above the line that says return *YES*.

```
UIViewController * launchScreenView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LaunchScreen" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
launchScreenView.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:launchScreenView.view];
```